# adding stopwatch to code that runs parallel to main thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, stopwatch

I am creating a runner app where the user can keep track of his run time and route.. On clicking START the camera should focus to current location and the timer textview should start updating lapsed time is seconds. Also as the user moves the google map should start plotting the marker according to the users current location.

```
Here is the code I have written so far
package com.example.kanchan.runner7;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Handler;


//1
public class HomeScreen extends FragmentActivity//,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
        implements View.OnClickListener,
        LocationListener {
    private  Button  buttonstart;
    private Button  buttonreset;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    private List<LatLng> routePoints ;
    private Marker TP;
    private Marker TP1;
    private Polyline route1;

    private Location loc;

    private TextView tv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Kimi","onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        buttonstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonstart.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonreset.setOnClickListener(this);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        routePoints =  new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        //route1 = new Polyline();

        // TP=  new MarkerOptions().position((new LatLng(0,0)));
        loc = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                buttonstartclick();
                break;



        }
    }


    private void buttonstartclick() {


        Log.d("Kimi..","kimi start button clicked");
        mMap.clear();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()), 14));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        stopwatch s = new stopwatch();

        s.startThread();

        while (true)
        {
            int[] curTime = s.getTime();
            Log.d("Kimi result from time", Integer.toString(curTime[2]) );
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){}

            tv.setText(Integer.toString(curTime[2]));

        }



    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
       /* mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
         TP = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("TutorialsPoint"));*/

    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(TP1 != null)
            TP1.remove();

        Log.d("Kimi..",Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
        Log.d("Kimi..",Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
        loc = location;

   /*   mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
*/
        TP = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red2)));
        TP1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));


    }



    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Kimi","status");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Kimi","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Kimi","disable");
    }
}
```

This code seems to be working fine if in buttonstartclick() I remove the portion for stopwatch(actually times as it will be incremantal.stopwatch class extens Thread in my code). The camera focusses to current user location and as user moved the markers are placed on map

However after writing the timer code the camera stops moving at all on START.

Also the timer textview does not get updated with timer values inside the while loop although from the messages in log I can see that the getTime() method returns correct value that should be upadted

The while loop also does not seem to be running in parallel main thread because on user location change I cant see the new markers being placed on the map.

Could anyone please suggest a way to add stopwatch feature to my code

Stopwatch code:

```
public class stopwatch extends Thread
{
    private long startTime;
    private boolean started;

    public void startThread()
    {
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.started = true;
        this.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (started)
        {
            // empty code since currentTimeMillis increases by itself
        }
    }


    public int[] getTime()
    {
        long milliTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startTime;
        int[] out = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
        out[0] = (int)(milliTime / 3600000      );
        out[1] = (int)(milliTime / 60000        ) % 60;
        out[2] = (int)(milliTime / 1000         ) % 60;
        out[3] = (int)(milliTime)                 % 1000;

        return out;
    }

    public void stopThread()
    {
        this.started = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without saying your stopwatch code, but Android has a Chronometer class which is pretty easy to use and could serve you well. And if I may, your stopwatch class should start with an uppercase letter I think.

Comment: added the stopwatch code

Comment: I think the given answer is correct except for the the advice on creating an inner class. For me your case is a text book case where the Observer pattern would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I skimmed through the code but seems you're implementation of stopwatch ist not present

Nevertheless when you click on start button you initialize everytime a new instance of ints
then you call this ominous start thread method

And then entering an infinite loop running on the main thread and essentially blocking other operations without an if clause to leave it by the way
also initialising every time a new array of int filling it with the callback gettime ()

This should not be processed on the ui thread but in a seperate thread maybe an inner class one so that you can easily accessible the members and methods of your activity class

Your app should just freeze waiting for your while loop to end that's why no drawings no updates etc are made

Well your text view is updated but not drawn at all because of your implementation

Comment: Thnkas for response.. Could you explain more on how  to "This should not be processed on the ui thread but in a seperate thread maybe an inner class one so that you can easily accessible the members and methods of your activity class"  . Some tutorial will also be fine

Comment: So first I would NOT let the run method empty...that's where the magic should take place... by magic i mean the refreshing of the text view plus the incrementing of the time ... and i would give that thread object a reference to the text view. ..keep in mind to assure that it is non-null when writing to it ofc..I will post a new answer with a code for you again

Comment: thanks for the response..tried tis today ..it dint work exactly but gave me a good idea.. finally achived it using AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

OK here you go:
(I see no code button)
delTime is the time went by
oldTime is the starting time 
tv is the reference to the textview

```
public void run ()
{
oldTime=System.cur...;
while (running)
{
    setDeltaTime (); //computes the time went by.
    int hours=(int)(delTime/3600000);

    int minutes=(int)((delTime-hours*3600000)/60000);

    int seconds=(int)((delTime-hours*3600000-             minutes*6000)/1000);

    String s=""   +(hours <10?"0":"")
                          +hours
                          +":"
                          +(minutes<10?"0":"")
                          +minutes
                          +":"
                          +(second <10?"0":"")
                          +seconds;

   tv.setText (s);

   relax ()//give the thread some relaxation (sleep ());


}

}
```

So you get the text view updated in 00:00:00 format and it is off the ui thread ... So you don't block it

(I see you want mills too then just extend this example...and imho no need to make a method that returns an array also no need for a boolean to check whether thread is running since thread class has a callback for it ...isAlive ()...and not good to set it before the thread has started actually runtime exception could have been thrown at start () maybe try catch would also be appropriate )